# Does casting a generic type using the dynamic keyword cause boxing?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

Will the following code cause boxing of the integer passed into the call to `GenericMethod`?

```
void GenericMethod<T>(T value)
{
  int test = (dynamic)value;
}

void Main()
{
  GenericMethod(100);
}
```

Comment: The dynamic dispatch is going to be orders of magnitude more expensive than boxing, so it's not even really relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to C# specification **§4.7 The dynamic type**:

> `dynamic` is considered identical to `object` except in the following respects:
>
> - Operations on expressions of type `dynamic` can be dynamically bound (§7.2.2).
> - Type inference (§7.5.2) will prefer `dynamic` over `object` if both are candidates.

So, casting to `dynamic` cause boxing in the same way as casting to `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see IL code to see if boxing is there :

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> class Test.Program/'<>o__0`1'<!!T>::'<>p__0'
IL_0006: brfalse.s IL_000a
IL_0008: br.s IL_002e
IL_000a: ldc.i4.0
IL_000b: ldtoken [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0010: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_0015: ldtoken Test.Program
IL_001a: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_001f: call class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder::Convert(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags,  class [mscorlib]System.Type,  class [mscorlib]System.Type)
IL_0024: call class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>>::Create(class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder)
IL_0029: stsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> class Test.Program/'<>o__0`1'<!!T>::'<>p__0'
IL_002e: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> class Test.Program/'<>o__0`1'<!!T>::'<>p__0'
IL_0033: ldfld !0 class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>>::Target
IL_0038: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> class Test.Program/'<>o__0`1'<!!T>::'<>p__0'
IL_003d: ldarg.0
IL_003e: box !!T
IL_0043: callvirt instance int32 class [mscorlib]System.Func`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>::Invoke(!0,  !1)
IL_0048: stloc.0
IL_0049: ret
```

As you can see from this line of code :

```
IL_003e: box !!T
```

It boxes the int

Comment: I like your answer cause it taught me a thing about IL code, though PetSerAI had you by a few minutes. I'm torn between which aspect matters more.

Comment: Thank you and no worries, i am glad that my answer was somewhat helpful. FYI you can inspect IL code using any decompiling tool, such as ReSharper dotCover or Telerik's 'JustDecompile' (JD)

Comment: I've actually used ILSpy a few times in the past, but never realized there was an explicit "box" opcode.

Answer (score 0):

Variables of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type object, type dynamic exists only at compile time, not at run time.

So, actually your example makes cast to an object that is a reference type. Boxing exists here